# Filtering data using QGIS Atlas

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have some mining data that I want to filter by year and by bench. The data is something like this:

```
bench   year
1      2020
1      2021
1      2022
2      2020
2      2021
2      2022
4      2020
4      2020
4      2021
4      2021
4      2022
3      2020
3      2021
3      2022
3      2023
```

This is a polygon layer with squares representing each bench. Each bench has a different year when they will be mined. some of these polygons have the same location (same X,Y but different Z value), different bench number, but will be mined at a different year.

I want to create several maps that can filter the data by year; e.g. These are all the benches that are going to be mined in 2020. Then I want to do it by bench; e.g bench 4 will be mined in 2020, 2021 and 2022.

I was wondering if I can do this with Atlas?

Comment: In QGIS 3.14 a temporal controller has been added: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog314/index.html#temporal. It is also available in layout manager. Unfortunately I don't know how to use it yet

Comment: Not sure if there is a current methodology for this kind of filtering. The only things I could suggest are either 1.creating duplicates of the layer and using 'Themes', 2.Filtering the layer and just manually exporting each view (not using Atlas), 3.Look to combine the data in a new layer using dissolve (specifying a field to use) to create a layer for each 'set' that you need e.g. a 2020 layer (with all relevant benches) or a Bench1 layer (with all relevant years)

Comment: That is good idea. What I currently do is:

Comment: 1 Make a duplicate layer 2. Use "Categorized" as Symbology; to group the data that I need (by year for on layer, by bench for the other) 3. Then I use "Query Builder" (or right-click > Filter...) to filter the data for each layer. This is fine but if I need to make corrections I have to go back and  correct each view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.
To do it for each bench per year:

1. Dissolve layer. make sure you choose **bench** as your **Dissolve field(s)**
2. Choose this newly dissolved layer as your atlas **Coverage Layer** and choose **bench** as **Page name**
3. In the original layer go to **Properties** and select **Rule-Based**
4. Add a rule for each year and do the following: [image: rule-based symbology]
   something like this:

   `"year" = 2020 AND  "Bench" = @atlas_pagename`

Now all I did was duplicate the original layer and do this time dissolve by year and change the rule to

`"bench" = 2 AND   "year"  =  @atlas_pagename`

do this for every bench

This can also work for a graduated symbology. Something like this:

`"field_name" >= 0.0 AND "field_name" <= 20.0 AND "field_to_filter" = @atlas_pagename`